# Toggle class on div = Untoggle class on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some divs (#div1, #div2, #div3) that change appearence  on click, they toggle a class using this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#parent_div").on('click', '.current_class', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("new_class");
    });
});
```

Now I want the the divs to be unable to toggle at the same time, so they work kinda like a radio-button with same `"name"`.

Example: Imagine three divs that looks the same (default class), then you click on one of the divs (example #div1) and that one toggles a new class and change appearence. Now you click on one of the other two and this one also change appearence (toggle class), at the same time when this one change appearence #div1 changes back to the default class.

So there can only be one div of those three that toggles the new class at once.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to remove the class from all the divs, and then add it to the current one. Try this:

```
$("#parent_div").on('click', '.current_class', function () {
    $('#parent_div .new_class').removeClass('new_class'); // remove exisiting
    $(this).addClass("new_class"); // add to current
});
```

**Update**

Added functionality to remove class from current:

```
$("#parent_div").on('click', '.current_class', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('new_class')) {
        $('#parent_div .new_class').removeClass('new_class');
        $this.addClass("new_class");
    }
    else {
        $this.removeClass("new_class");
    }
});
```

Comment: This one worked great after adding the doc.ready part, but its impossible to untoggle the current (if dont want to toggle non), is this possible to add?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#parent_div").on('click', '.current_class', function (){
        if($(this).hasClass('.new_class')){
            $(this).removeClass('.new_class');
        }else {
            $('.new_class').removeClass('.new_class');
            $(this).addClass('.new_class');
        }
    });
});
```

**Updated**: Code now allows for toggling of current element with class `.new_class`.

Comment: This one worked great, but its impossible to untoggle the current (if dont want to toggle non), is this possible to add?

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible, but you'll need to reset all the other divs manually.

An example would be :

I have 3 divs available with id's div-1, div-2 and div-3. 
I'm using a default class 'default' and a definition class so i can click them 'clickable', and my other class would be 'selected'.

To implement this you would need to do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $('#parent-div').on('click, 'clickable', function() {
        $('.selected').removeClass("selected").addClass("default");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    })
});
```

I hope this helps. 
I didn't have the possibility to check if the syntax is exactly correct, but I believe this does the job as required.

Kind regards,
NDakotaBE